# API/ Microservice specific testing using gatling

Tags: scala-gatling

I am new to scala and gatling . Till now i have recorded scenario specific simulation using gatling but I would like to know how to perform load on each API individually.

In my scenario, I have different API like loginservice, accountservice and message service and since recorded scenarios are scenario specific they are not actually performing load test on each API individually.

I want to perform load test on each API separately and check the performance.

Kindly let me know the way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You could write different different Simulation classes for each APi or even write it in the same scenario. Depends on how to run them. The gatling documentation is pretty useful in this case. Also you could check the google group for gatling for more answers!